# Drupal: Are hook_ functions in *.api.php ever called?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

In Drupal 7, every core module has a `*.api.php` file, where * is the name of the module.  For example

```
modules/node/node.api.php
modules/path/path.api.php
```

What are these files for?  They contain functions that start with `hook_`, and the name of a hook that (I think) the module invokes.  For example

```
modules/system/system.api
```

has

```
function hook_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $entity->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $additional_field,
    '#weight' => 10,
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
  );
}
```

There's an `entity_view` hook that's invoked by the system which you may implement in your own modules, but (it doesn't appear) that `hook_entity_view` is ever called.

What are these function for.  Are they ever called by the system?  If so, when?  If not, why are they there?

Comment: just spent an hour trying to figure out if they are ever called. I should have searched the net first instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, it's just documentation files that describe hooks by modules.
About hook_entity_view: you can add it in custom module: YOURMODULENAME_entity_view(...).

Comment: Got it.  Follow up question: Why is entity_view considered part of the system module?  What makes a particular hook (entity_view, node_insert) a part of a particular module?  Is it just an arbitrary grouping, or is there something that binds a particular hook to a particular module?

Comment: @Alan Storm: Any module may invoke any hook so there's no hard binding. The system module might be a special case as it probably documents some of the core API:s as well.