# about hook: What is the role of hook_*()

Tags: drupal, hook

For example in the user module there is a `hook_user_login`  hook

When a user logs in in `function user_login_finalize()` will be called, then  `user_login_finalize` will call `user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user)`;
that will call `system_user_login` (and others module's function[`moudulename_user_login`]  that implements `hook_user_login()`);

I am puzzled at which function will `call hook_user_login（）` and  when it will be Invoked. What is the role of this function?

Comment: Go to the docs page for the hook you want info on, click on the collapsed "x invocation(s) of hook_name()" and you'll see what functions invoke it. The docs page will explain what the hook is for, if you're struggling with English ask someone with more experience in it to help you; we can't help you with translation issues here for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the `user_login_finalize` will call `user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user)`.

The `user_module_invoke` function will then look at the first argument of the function (login) and based on that value it will call the `hook_user_login()` function.

The main goal for a module to implement the hook_user_login() function is to be notified that a user just logged in, so it can take additional actions: add additional information to the database, write a special message to the screen if it is the user his/her birthday, etc ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999138/drupal-are-hook-functions-in-api-php-ever-called   i found a similar question and the answer say the hood_xxx() function just documentation files that describe hooks by modules. i am puzzled  now.